# ¿Core dumped? Webpack vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

desde hace algunos dias vengo teniendo unos problemas con mi webpack, es para ejecutar vuejs 2.

El problema es constante y cada vez que guardo el webpack compila despues de 3 o 4 compilaciones me arroja el siguiente error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[2263:0x27c5b20]  4016253 ms: Mark-sweep 1390.9 (1419.0) -> 1390.3 (1418.5) MB, 61.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.122, current mu = 0.039) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[2263:0x27c5b20]  4016325 ms: Mark-sweep 1391.0 (1418.5) -> 1390.5 (1418.5) MB, 70.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.079, current mu = 0.027) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x324988edbe1d]
Security context: 0x13f8df21e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: from [0x13f8df2068e1](this=0x13f8df206739 <JSFunction Array (sfi = 0x1052f08ff59)>,0x24c819742271 <Set map = 0x187ce1e3ed71>,0x352f955cb979 <JSFunction obj.chunks.module.mapChunks.chunk (sfi = 0x465bd1f64b9)>)
    2: fnModule(aka fnModule) [0x1b07ab57ed11] [/home/superaccess/portal-web-2.0/Superaccess2.0/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:~321] [pc=0x3...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8f9d10 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8f9d5c  [node]
 3: 0xaffd0e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xafff44 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xef4152  [node]
 6: 0xef4258 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xf00332 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xf00c64 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xf038d1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xecc9c6 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
11: 0xecd24a v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: 0xecd807 v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
13: 0xe8ecb0  [node]
14: 0xe8ee9f  [node]
15: 0x1005fee v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [node]
16: 0x101f752 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [node]
17: 0x1024ba0 v8::internal::JSObject::DefineOwnPropertyIgnoreAttributes(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::JSObject::AccessorInfoHandling) [node]
18: 0x102a685 v8::internal::JSObject::CreateDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [node]
19: 0x10398f8 v8::internal::JSReceiver::CreateDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [node]
20: 0x1199b5e v8::internal::Runtime_CreateDataProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
21: 0x324988edbe1d
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Pienso que es un problema de memoria, la cuestion es que el error se empezo a presentar de una semana hacia al dia de hoy, verificamos todos los cambios y no hay cambios significativos, asi que realice unos ajustes a mi ubuntu server y le deje 3Gb de ram (antes tenia 1.5 con lo que funcionaba perfecto) y aun asi se presenta este error, no he podido encontrar solucion espero que alguien me pueda apoyar, gracias y saludos desde Colombia.

Comment: Puede ser que tu versión de node sea muy vieja

Comment: Lo acabo de verificar y la version que estoy utilizando es las 10.16 actualmente es la recomendada por node en su pag :/

Comment: ¿has probado con las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343298/895789)?

Comment: Asi es y aun no he dado con la solucion :/ por ahora lo unico que me queda es reiniciar webpack cada vez que ocurre